# Doctrine query error on leftJoin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I wrote this query.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select(['cart','subscriptions', 'member'])
    ->from('ComitiUserBundle:Cart', 'cart')
    ->leftJoin('cart.subscriptions', 'subscriptions')
    ->leftJoin('subscriptions.member', 'member')
    ->where('cart.club = :club_id')
    ->andWhere('subscriptions.clubSeason = :season_id')
    ->setParameter('club_id', $club)
    ->setParameter('season_id', $season);
    if($section != null && !is_array($section)){
        $query->andWhere('subscriptions.section = :section_id')
        ->setParameter('section_id', $section);
    } elseif($section != null && is_array($section)){
        $query->andWhere('subscriptions.section IN :section_ids')
        ->setParameter('section_ids', $section);
    }
    $query->orderBy('cart.transaction_date','DESC');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I've got this error in return :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 28: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'member'

In fact I try to hydrate my result collection with members in it. Member is manyToOne property in my Subscription entity. It is defined like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\UserComiti", inversedBy="subscriptions", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $member;
```

Comment: Look at error. Error said you had got syntax error in subquery

Comment: What you posted seems right.  Comment out everything after the second leftJoin just to verify it is the join.  And of course do the clear cache thing if you just modified your associations.

Comment: The query you posted is in a Controller, or in a Repository ? If it's a repository, it's related to which entity ?

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into the exact same error when trying to join a category group for a category entity. See the code below:

```
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from(Category::class, 'c');

        if (isset($fields['categoryGroup'])) {
            $qb = $qb->join('c.categoryGroup', 'group')
                ->addSelect('group');
        }

        $qb = $qb->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

This resulted in the exact same error as the OP, only with 'group'. My guess is that you cannot use database reserved words in the query, like `group` and `member`.

For me, changing the alias to something like `cg` worked just fine.

Comment: Had the same problem, using 'as' as alias. Your post helped, thanks!